# Create timestamped labels on csv files (ruby code)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am running a transaction download script through Ruby. I was wondering if it is possible to label each .csv it creates with the current date/time the script was run. Below is the end of the script.

```
CSV.open("transaction_report.csv", "w") do |csv|
  csv << header_row
  search_results.each do |transaction|
    transaction_details_row = header_row.map{ |attribute| transaction.send(attribute) }
    csv << transaction_details_row
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
CSV.open("transaction_report-#{Time.now}.csv", "w") do |csv|
  csv << header_row
  search_results.each do |transaction|
    transaction_details_row = header_row.map{ |attribute| transaction.send(attribute) }
    csv << transaction_details_row
  end
end
```

This just appends the time of generation to the file name. For example:

```
"transaction_report-#{Time.now}.csv"
# => "transaction_report-2019-10-10 16:09:07 +0100.csv"
```

If you want to avoid spaces in the file name, you can sub these out like so:

```
"transaction_report-#{Time.now.to_s.gsub(/\s/, '-')}.csv"
# => "transaction_report-2019-10-10-16:09:40-+0100.csv"
```

Is that what you're after? It sounds right based on the question, though happy to update if you're able to correct me :)

Comment: The default action is that Ruby opens up, lists transaction batches it is pulling from Braintree, and creates a file. When I modify the last part of the code with "transaction_report-#{Time.zone.now}.csv", it opens up Ruby interpreter and closes immediately.

Comment: Ah - that's my bad @Andrew. `Time.zone.now` is Rails specific, not available in core Ruby: I've updated to use `Time.now` which should do what you're after. Let me know how you get on!

Comment: It seems to have the same error as last time. Does Ruby have an issue with doing functions inside quotes?

Comment: Did you get this working @Andrew? That's standard string interpolation, so certainly shouldn't be an issue with the current implementation. Do you get an error message? If so, post in the question and I'll take a look.